# IP address of the client who is using my sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm using the event receiver in a feature to deal with changes in my SharePoint site and I want the IP address of the client who is updating any lists in my site.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From a synchronous server-side ER (not in an App), you may simply get the IP address with:

```
if(HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    // Look for a proxy address first
    _ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    // If there is no proxy, get the standard remote address
    if (_ip == null || _ip.ToLower() == "unknown")
        _ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

(code adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726576/system-web-httpcontext-current-request-userhostaddress).
Note the test on `HttpContext.Current` since the ER may be trigerred by PowrShell, job or else (i.e. not in an HTTP context).

Comment: can you show me an example how to use it and can i add it to my feature